# Compare Groovy dates ignoring days

Tags: datetime, groovy

How can I compare dates in Groovy ignoring days? Something like this: ***MM-yyyy_1 > MM-yyyy_2***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
int compareIgnoringDays( Date a, Date b ) {
  new Date( a.time ).with { newa ->
    new Date( b.time ).with { newb ->
      newa.set( date:1 )
      newb.set( date:1 )
      newa.compareTo( newb )
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can test like:

```
Date a = Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd', '2012/05/23' )
Date b = Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd', '2012/05/24' )
Date c = Date.parse( 'yyyy/MM/dd', '2012/06/01' )

assert compareIgnoringDays( a, b ) == 0
assert compareIgnoringDays( b, a ) == 0
assert compareIgnoringDays( a, c ) == -1
assert compareIgnoringDays( c, a ) == 1
```

A different way of writing the same functionality is:

```
int compareIgnoringDays( Date a, Date b ) {
  [ a, b ].collect { new Date( it.time ) }   // Clone original dates
          .collect { it.set( date:1 ) ; it } // Set clones to 1st of the month
          .with { newa, newb ->
            newa.compareTo( newb )           // Compare them (this gets returned)
          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to explore this since I havent thinkerd a lot with Groovy but I'm guessing this is the right approach.

Comment: It basically sets copies of the two dates to be the first of the month, and then compares these Dates...  Beware of time if it is set, as obviously this will affect things...  Groovy has a [`Date.clearTime()` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#clearTime%28%29) which you might need to make use of if times are going to be in your dates, but not your comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two dates like this:

```
def myFormat = 'MM/dd/yyyy'
if(Date.parse(myFormat, '02/03/2012') >= Date.parse(myFormat, '03/02/2012))
{...}
```